# calculating average in Spark streaming not working : issue w/ updateStateByKey and instantiating class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to take a stock ticker and value entered via Linux command's nc in a streaming context, and return an average every minute or so.

Values are entered in the format (String, Double), i.e. USD 20.
My design is, I want to get these values (1 string and value per line) and instantiate a "Visit" class with them. Then use this class (as well as "VisitState" class to count) to use for my updateStateByKey streaming method.

Here is what i ve tried:

```
    // Create a ReceiverInputDStream on target ip:port and count the
    // words in input stream of \n delimited test (eg. generated by 'nc')
    val  lines:ReceiverInputDStream = ssc.socketTextStream(args(0), args(1).toInt)

    val words:RDD[String] = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))  
    val wordDstream :DStream[(String, Double)] = words.map(x => (x(1).toString, x(2).toDouble))

    // Update function that will compute state after each dstream ingestion
    val update = (vals: Seq[Double], state: Option[VisitState]) => {
       val prev = state.getOrElse(VisitState())
       val currentCount = prev.count + vals.size
       val newAvg = (prev.average * prev.count + vals.sum)/currentCount
      Some(new VisitState(currentCount, newAvg))

    }
  val state:DStream[(String, VisitState)] = wordDstream.updateStateByKey[VisitState](update)
```

and here is my classes:

```
case class Visit(label: String, marketValue: Int)
  extends Serializable 
{
  private var id : String = ""
  private var value : Int = 0
  this.id = label.toString
  this.value = marketValue

  override def toString():String = {label+s", value=$marketValue"} 
}
```

and

```
case class VisitState(count: Double = 0L, average: Double = 0L) {
```

}

I have 2 issues:

- compile error: value updateStateByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[Visit]
  [error]       val state:DStream[(String, VisitState)] = wordDstream.updateStateByKeyVisit
- i dont know how to instantiate my class w/ the values in Scala, really. I m not sure how.

any help ? 
cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first error, I wouldn't use `flatMap` but just `map`:

```
val words = lines.map(line => line.split(" "))
val wordsTuple = words.map(line => (line(0).toString, line(1).toDouble)
```

For the second point, you could do something like

```
val visits = wordsTuple.map(line => (line._1, new Visit(line._1, line._2)))
def update(values: Seq[Visit], state: Option[VisitState]) {
     ...
}
val visitStates = visits.updateStateByKey[VisitState](update)
```

Comment: thanks! what is your Value class in the 2nt point, did you mean 'Visit'? with those changes, now i m getting  `value _1 is not a member of Nothing
[error]    val valuesTuple = wordsTuple.map(line => (line._1, new Visit(line._1, line._2)))`     and     `value updateStateByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[Nothing]
[error]       val state:DStream[(String, VisitState)] = valuesTuple.updateStateByKey[VisitState](update)` , any idea ?